# Converge in distribution and Equal in distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a silly question may be due to the definition of converge in distribution.

Say $\{X_n\}$ and $\{Y_n\}$ are two sequence of random variables; for each $n$, $X_n$ and $Y_n$ have the same distribution. Now we know that $X_n$ weakly converges to $X$ and $Y_n$ weakly converges $Y$.

It seems straightforward to say that $X$ and $Y$ are equal in distribution, and it looks like one can easily show so by using the Portmanteau Theorem, i.e, to show that $P(X\leq s)=P(Y\leq s)$ for any real value $s$. Such a statement holds if $s$ is the continuous point of the CDFs of $X$ and $Y$. But how to discuss the case if $s$ is not the continuous point of CDF of $X$ or $Y$? How to show that CDFs of $X$ and $Y$ are continuous and discontinuous at the same points?

Comment: I think [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1269324/proving-the-uniqueness-of-the-weak-limit) is related.

Comment: The topology of weak convergence is metrizable.

Comment: By right continuity, two CDF's which agree on a dense set agree everywhere.